# What are the resources that are held by statement object

Tags: java, jdbc

For a JDBC Connection, I'm aware that Java will create a socket with port number and open stream of connection between it and the DB server with its specified port number, database name and maybe other options, closing this resource is clearly needed.

But for `Statement`, alongside with `ResultSet`, what are the resources that are held by them so we need to close them? I mean technically.

Comment: For a `ResultSet`, it's the database cursor. Basically, a database will not always retrieve all the results eagerly - rather, it will keep a temporary index of references to the results themselves and retrieve them on demand. The resource is freed when you close the `ResultSet`. 

For a `PreparedStatement` (usually not for a normal `Statement`), a prepared statement on the server.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin Why use a comment to answer? You could have posted this as a  real answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whether resources are actually held by a statement or result set, depends very much on the specific database and driver.

A `Statement` in Java could have a counterpart (statement handle) in the database, with some memory for a statement, configuration like timeouts, fetch size, buffers, etc. For a plain `Statement` this is not always the case, but for `PreparedStatement` the statement handle in the database will usually hold a version of the compiled statement with its execution plan, etc.

Closing the statement object in Java will release this handle in the database (or maybe free it for reuse for a different statement), and might for example release 'existence locks' on metadata (eg preventing a table from being dropped while it is still being used/prepared). Also, closing the statement in Java will close any open result sets, which could then free memory in Java and the database.

Closing the result set itself also has clear benefits, a result set may hold memory in Java (eg prefetched rows, sometimes the full result), so closing the result set will release those pre-fetched rows and free memory. This especially applies if you haven't fully read the result set, or if you are using a scrollable result set.

A result set may also have a cursor (or similar) on the database side which points to the last row fetched, locks on rows (eg in a `for update` select statement), and maybe it also holds a number of pre-fetched rows in memory. Closing the result set will release the memory and any locks, etc.

In other words: yes, you should close result sets and statements, and you should do so as soon as you are done with them.